# Identity Server Assembly Load Exception

Tags: identity-server

I have ported our identity provider from integrated with Sitecore directly over to the identity server.  After getting the configuration set up, my provider is getting loaded and configured, but then fails because it wants `Microsoft.Identitymodel.Tokens.Saml` version `5.2.4.0`.  I have copied this into both the root of the identity server as well as the refs directory.  I have tried to set the right dependency version for this in `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.deps.json` (it was set to 5.2.0), which leads to a 502.5 - Process Failure error.

The .NET framework has assembly load logging, but I have been unable to find any equivalent for .NET core.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run the identity server from a command prompt as an Administrator, so you can see what the errors are.

run this: `dotnet Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.dll`

I had to update versions of several assemblies, and update the `Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.deps.json` file.